# modificar action de formulario y enviarlo con jQuery

Tags: jquery

Estoy teniendo problemas para enviar un formulario al que le cambio el action a través de jQuery.

El html del formulario es:

```
<form class="js-quest-form-quest" id="quest-form-action" method="post" action="">
```

Lo estoy cambiando de esta forma:

```
$('#quest-form-action').attr('action', 'url');
```

Y puedo ver cómo el action se actualiza en el DOM. Posteriormente envío el formulario con:

```
$('.js-quest-form-quest').submit();
```

Pero por alguna razón el formulario no se envía a la URL que le he metido en el action.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes intentar realizar el submit sin jquery con javascript puro de esta forma:

```
document.getElementById('quest-form-action').submit() por las dudas.
```